# Assigning a value to a new variable in a Crystal macro

Tags: macros, crystal-lang

I would like to create a new variable in a macro. My code can be reduce to:

```
macro test()
  %p = "a = 3"
  %p
end

test()
puts(a)
```

but i then get an error `undefined local variable or method 'a'`

I tried to wrap the `%p` in `{{ }}` or `{% %}` but it does not compile ("`unexpected token: %`")

EDIT

Here is some context.

I often have to use a two named tuples with some common fields that are then converted to JSON and sent to different clients.

```
a = {x: xx, y: yy, w: ww}
b = {x: xx, y: yy, z: zz}
```

Currently I writing both of them with a repetition. Values for ww,xx,yy,zz are not known at compile-time. I would like to replace that with a call to a macro doing the merge at compile-time.

I came up with the following code that is creating the line of code I currently input manually:

```
macro merge(common, aOnly, bOnly)
  # Start, middle and end parts of target instructions
  %p1a = "a = {"
  %p1b = "b = {"
  %p2 = ""
  %p2a = ""
  %p2b = ""
  %p3 = "}"

  # Creating the middle part
  {% for key, value in common %}
    %p2 = %p2 + "{{key.id}}" + ": " + "{{value}}" + ','
  {% end %}
  %p2a = %p2
  {% for key, value in aOnly %}
    %p2a = %p2a + "{{key.id}}" + ": " + "{{value}}" + ','
  {% end %}
  %p2b = %p2
  {% for key, value in bOnly %}
    %p2b = %p2b + "{{key.id}}" + ": " + "{{value}}" + ','
  {% end %}

  # Removing unneeded comma
  %p2a = %p2a.chomp(",")
  %p2b = %p2b.chomp(",")

  #  Display
  puts(%p1a + %p2a + %p3)
  puts(%p1b + %p2b + %p3)

  # Definition of new variables
  %p1a + %p2a + %p3
  %p1b + %p2b + %p3
end

merge({x: xx, y: yy}, {w: ww}, {z: zz})
```

Comment: [Your program](https://carc.in/#/r/1nfd) expands to: `__temp_22 = "a = 3"; __temp_22; puts(a)`, which is what I would expect given this syntax, but you probably expected something different. But it's not possible to guess what you expected, so please expand your question.

Comment: I added some context.

Comment: Macros can't define new variables. Variables are determined at parse time. For example if you do `a = 1` inside a method, the parser now knows that `a` is a variable. If you do that inside a macro call the parser doesn't know about it. And that's not a bug, it's a language feature. Making variables suddenly appear in a method is bug prone and confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here is misunderstanding of `%names`. This is not a construct that makes instructions compile time. Writing `%a = 5` is the same as writing `guaranteed_unique_name = 5` – it's a way to avoid interfering with other variables that may exist in the same scope, but it's still a normal runtime variable assignment.

Constructing strings and then outputting them at compile time is not a viable approach to using macros, and it almost always ends up being impossible, because you can't reassign a different value to a macro variable. But here's an example of what it might look like if it actually worked, still trying to use your approach with strings:

```
macro merge(common, aOnly, bOnly)
  # Start, middle and end parts of target instructions
  {%
    p1a = "a = {"
    p1b = "b = {"
    p2 = ""
    p2a = ""
    p2b = ""
    p3 = "}"
  %}

  # Creating the middle part
  {% for key, value in common %}
    {% p2 = p2 + "#{key.id}: #{value}," %}
  {% end %}
  {% p2a = p2 %}
  {% for key, value in aOnly %}
    {% p2a += "#{key.id}: #{value}," %}
  {% end %}
  {% p2b = p2 %}
  {% for key, value in bOnly %}
    {% p2b += "#{key.id}: #{value}," %}
  {% end %}

  # Removing unneeded comma
  {% p2a = p2a.chomp(",") %}
  {% p2b = p2b.chomp(",") %}

  # Definition of new variables
  {{(p1a + p2a + p3).id}}
  {{(p1b + p2b + p3).id}}
end

merge({x: xx, y: yy}, {w: ww}, {z: zz})
```

Now I will just rewrite your example with more usual constructs:

```
macro merge(common, a_only, b_only)
  a = {
    {% for key, value in common %}
      {{key}}: {{value}},
    {% end %}
    {% for key, value in a_only %}
      {{key}}: {{value}},
    {% end %}
  }

  b = {
    {% for key, value in common %}
      {{key}}: {{value}},
    {% end %}
    {% for key, value in b_only %}
      {{key}}: {{value}},
    {% end %}
  }
end

merge({x: "a", y: 5}, {w: "b"}, {z: 7})

pp a, b
```

As you can see, the normal code you put in a macro's body is runtime code while things inside `{% %}` and `{{ }}` are executed at compile time. You can make compile time loops and intertwine them with normal code lines to create complex code naturally.

Hopefully that answers the question title "Assigning a value to a new variable in a Crystal macro": to assign something to a runtime variable you do the same thing as for outputting any runtime code in a macro – you just write it out, like `a = 5`, because by default macros output runtime code, and only `{%` and `{{` delimit compile time constructs.

---

To reply to a comment, here is perhaps an even more idiomatic version, and it even illustrates the temporary/unique variable names. It uses them to create tuples and then the result of the macro's execution is a tuple of those which can be conveniently unpacked, instead of relying on side effects, which is rarely done.

```
macro merge(common, a_only, b_only)
  %a = {
    {% for key, value in common %}
      {{key}}: {{value}},
    {% end %}
    {% for key, value in a_only %}
      {{key}}: {{value}},
    {% end %}
  }

  %b = {
    {% for key, value in common %}
      {{key}}: {{value}},
    {% end %}
    {% for key, value in b_only %}
      {{key}}: {{value}},
    {% end %}
  }

  { %a, %b }
end

first, second = merge({x: "a", y: 5}, {w: "b"}, {z: 7})

puts first
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I understand how the second version is more idiomatic. However, I don't get why I can't use "puts" to display the variables a and b. Doing that, it get the message "undefined local variable or method 'a' ".

Comment: @ClementJ., hmm, this is a bit of a strange behavior, borderline a bug. Macros aren't usually used to create new variables with a hardcoded name, so this is not a well researched part of the language. I guess you need to "anticipate" the variable before calling a macro: `a = nil; merge({x: "a", y: 5}, {w: "b"}, {z: 7}); puts a` ([full code](https://carc.in/#/r/1nfz))

Comment: @ClementJ., check the addition to my answer